# Next-auth cookie token malformed

Tags: next.js, next-auth

With Next-Auth, and CredentialsProvider, I'm trying to use the cookie to authenticate.

But I got this error in backend :

> error JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export default async function ProtectedApiRoute(
    req: any,
    res: any,
    requestHandler: any
) {
    try {
        const token = await getToken({
            req,
            secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
            raw: true,
            secureCookie: false,
        })
      
        // Here, this throw "JsonWebTokenError" jwt malformed
        const payload = jwt.verify(
            token,
            process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
            {
                maxAge: '1h',
            }
        )

        return requestHandler(req, res, payload)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        return new NextResponse(null, {
            status: 401,
        })
    }
}
```

In the browser, I saw that the token is strange :

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..sXGbpi_c9HBZBG0C.rmMpDdA81UUfOghN3IB5Tf80gcuK4xPk0o83Hd8sYMqLyooWXjg0jTA503hRkFmKOXLkyficKwdC_FEmpNiSObVxHvNzJL7L5H5XeHtxLplQcTKR-xDQTiSP-FOSFhgntowxy7Gd1sChY0giTGVDrAmaJydukQnxvXP5uXpbxxRP63L-X6Ini58.msljO3rYlC--MuhBZyN67A
```

It seems to be indeed malformed

Here my configuration :

```
import { login } from 'lib/auth'
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
const sign = require('jwt-encode')

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: '/signin',
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {}, // custom login form
            async authorize(credentials: any, req) {
                try {
                    const user = await login(
                        credentials.username,
                        credentials.password
                    )

                    return user
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('error', error)
                    return null
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user }) {
            if (user) return true

            return false
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            // add role to session
            // @ts-ignore
            session.role = token.role

            session.accessToken = sign(token, process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET)

            return session
        },
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            // add role to jwt
            if (user) token.role = (user as any).role
            return token
        },
    },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```